# Flowey's identity (spoiler)

Tags: undertale

Warning : this question will involve information contained in the True Pacifist run of Undertale. So be careful before reading.

At the end of the True Pacifist Run, we discover

> the true identity of Flowey. Flowey is in reality Asriel Dreemurr.

But I am still not sure of something. This could just be a theory, or this is maybe a point in the game that I've missed. But my suspicion is that

> Flowey's personality is split in two. Flowey could be Asriel Dreemurr and Chara.

I have always been asking myself this since I have finished the True Pacifist run, though the question emerged again today after I watched again the dialogue between

> Frisk and Asriel after the seal is broken. One part of the dialogue says :
>  "The control over our body was actually split between us.
>  They were the one that picked up their own empty body.
>  And then, when we got to the village...
>  They were the one that wanted to...
>  to use our full power.
>  I was the one that resisted.
>  And then, because of me, we...
>  Well, that's why I ended up a flower."

That part was strange for me. In fact, we know that

> Alphys was the one who injected Asriel's essence in the golden flower in which had been injected determination. But Asriel absorbed Chara's soul before going in the human world, so they kinda merged. Is that then possible that Chara was also transferred in the golden flower, and that both of them became Flowey ?

I would like your opinion on the question. Is there any information in the game which could confirm or invalidate this ?

(This question do not have for goal to debate on a theory, but to know if there is a concret element in the game which indicates if it can be certified or not).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as is opinion-based.

Comment: We don't generally do opinion-based questions here.  You'll need to pursue definitive answers that folks can back up with evidence.

Comment: An interesting theory. Unfortunately, this isn't really something that can be determined from the contents of the game. As there's no solid answer, this is better suited for a discussion forum than here.

Comment: Well, my question was more like "Is there any information in the game that really confirm it or invalide it", to be honest. I was not expecting to go in a full opinion-based theory thingy, but I wanted to know if I missed any information in the game that could answer this. If there's none, then nevermind.

Comment: From what I understand, Alphys' didn't *"inject Asriel's essence in the golden flower"*, just the determination. Asriel's *"dust spread across the garden"* when he died (Alphys doesn't seem to know this, and got the flower from there), and we know from the librarby that mosnters *"live on"* in the item their dust is spread onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to go into spoilers here... but this is directly contradicted by the Genocide version of events.

> Specifically, in the ending, you find out that Chara has merged with Frisk.

This is a direct quote from the ending (I would have put it earlier, but spoiler text is breaking on multiple paragraphs)

> Your power awakened me from death.

Comment: I could quote the whole ending, but it'd just be easier (if you didn't want to play a Genocide run) to just watch a video of it.

Comment: That's a fair point I've thought about, though I was not sure myself about it, as (SPOILERS) for me they only merge after the genocide run, when the player sign the contract so the game can get a "true reset", and Chara only appears in person after Flowey himself is killed. I'll wait to see if someone else has any other information to add, but I'll probably accept this answer.